# Python time.sleep script

Tags: python, loops, raspberry-pi

Hello I have got a little problem.
Made a little project with Raspberry Pi.
About project : There is a switch connected to doors, when the doors are opened the switch is pressed and Raspberry Pi writes date and time in to the file, but it does it every 2 seconds if doors are still open. I figured out how to change that time, but if I put longer sleep time then, if doors are closed but the sleep time has not passed, doors can be opened again and that won't be written in to the file. 
Here is my code for this. 
I have two led's connected to see when doors are closed and opened.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

def main():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

    GPIO.setup(23,GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.setup(24,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(25,GPIO.OUT)


    GPIO.output(25,True)

    while True:
        if GPIO.input(23):
             GPIO.output(24,True)
             GPIO.output(25,False)
             f = open('register','a')
             t = time.strftime("%Y.%m.%d. - %H:%M:%S")
             f.write('Doors opened ')
             f.write(t)
             f.write('\n')
             f.close()
        else:

             GPIO.output(24,False)
             GPIO.output(25,True)
             print "button false"

        time.sleep(0.1)

    GPIO.cleanup()



if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Basically, code checks every second if circuit is closed or not. If not it writes every second new text file with date and time , if not continues checking.
What I need is to write in to the file date and time when doors are opened and then wait for door closing.

Comment: Independent from your problem, I would recommend not to open and close the log file in the while loop. Just open the log file before entering the while loop and close it after the while loop.

Comment: Didn't work, now it did not write anything in file while this program was running, and when I pressed Ctrl+c it wrote all results in file but again with 2 seconds gap

Comment: @jjanko3 The reason everything was written when you quit the program is because Python buffers writes by default. For ways around this, see here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open Sorry I can't really help with the real problem! It would be very helpful if you edited the question to explain what all the numbers `23-25` represent.

Comment: This is scheme for the hardware. 23 - 25 are the GPIO pins
http://25.media.tumblr.com/c8c1ca25a4ec28f9626c03c53505ef65/tumblr_moj8psVUA81so209ao1_1280.jpg

Comment: What are you looking for? You want to make sure that door open/close events are recorded even if they take place in between iterations of the `while` loop?

Comment: @PatrickCollins I want that when doors are opened would write just once date and time in text file. Now it is writing in text file (if doors are opened) every one second. 
EG.
I open doors for 5 seconds and text file looks like this 
Doors opened 2013.09.16 - 16:00:01 | 
Doors opened 2013.09.16 - 16:00:02 | 
Doors opened 2013.09.16 - 16:00:03 | 
Doors opened 2013.09.16 - 16:00:04 | 
Doors opened 2013.09.16 - 16:00:05 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should record the last value read from the door switch and only log if the current value is different from the last value.

```
last_value = None #Set to None so it will always be different the first time.
while True:
    current_value = GPIO.input(23)
    if current_value != last_value:
        if current_value:
            GPIO.output(24,True)
            GPIO.output(25,False)
            #LOG STUFF
        else:
            GPIO.output(24,False)
            GPIO.output(25,True)
            print "button false"
    last_value = current_value
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import RPi.gpio as gpio
import time

open_door_pin = 23
red_light_pin = 24
green_light_pin = 25

gpio.setmode(gpio.bcm)

gpio.setup(open_door_pin, gpio.IN)
gpio.setup(red_light_pin, gpio.OUT)
gpio.setup(green_light_pin, gpio.OUT)

gpio.output(red_light_pin, False)
gpio.output(green_light_pin, True)

f = open('register','a')

while True:
  gpio.wait_for_edge(open_door_pin,gpio.BOTH)
  if gpio.input(open_door_pin):
    gpio.output(red_light_pin, True)
    gpio.output(green_light_pin, False)
    t = time.strftime("%Y.%m.%d. - %H:%M:%S")
    f.write('Doors opened ')
    f.write(t)
    f.write('\n')
  else:
    gpio.output(red_light_pin, False)
    gpio.output(green_light_pin, True)
    t = time.strftime("%Y.%m.%d. - %H:%M:%S")
    f.write('Doors closed ')
    f.write(t)
    f.write('\n')

f.close()
gpio.cleanup()
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation?